# Verificar valores entre dois dataframes e retornar o maior (Pyhton e Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparação

O problema é o seguinte: tenho um DataFrame que eu construí com informações de `index`, `Name` e `Total`. Podem acessar pelo [link (o formato dele é csv)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rwpwa6913w5596t/df?dl=0), mas podem ver resumidamente ele [aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIiwS.png)

O que quero fazer é (utilizando o pandas e python):
abrir esse DataFrame para comparar os valores da coluna `Total` entre índices diferentes e retornar o maior valor dessa comparação em um novo DataFrame, e se esses valores forem iguais apenas repetir o primeiro.

Seria como comparar o valor linha índice `0` (Bulbasaur) da coluna  `Total` vs os demais, e ele me retorna o maior valor de total numa nova coluna:

Exemplo do novo DataFrame:

```
#1 - #2 - vencedor
0 - 0 - 0 (comparar bulbasaur(318) e bulbasaur(318): vencedor(318) = bulbasaur(318))
0 - 1 - 1 (comparar bulbasaur(318) e ivysaur(405) :  vencedor = ivysaur(405))
0 - 4 - 0 (comparar bulbasaur(318) e charmander(309): vencedor = bulbasaur(318))
```

Se alguém puder clarear e me ajudar a resolver, agradeço desde já.

Comment: Você precisa apresentar dados e demonstrar o problema na própria pergunta (favor [edit]), em vez de postar esses links. Veja [Posso mostrar só um link pro meu site com problemas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1913/74) e as [dicas sobre exemplo mínimo](/help/mcve). Obrigado.

Answer (score -2):

Como você precisa fazer uma busca com o pandas, recomendo utilizar o método

> loc

ou

> groupby

Documentação do loc: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

Documentação do groupby:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Para obter os dados necessários, fiz um exemplo com **loc** utilizando uma tabela que relaciona clientes de cartão de crédito, mas pode ser qualquer uma, inclusive essa que foi informada. É bem simples, nesse exemplo aí, dentro de **banco.loc[]** são passados as condições e as colunas que quero trazer. utilizei o método max() para trazer o maior valor, porém dá uma lida na documentação depois para ver os outros métodos disponíveis:

```
import pandas as pd
url='/content/BankChurners.csv'
banco = pd.read_csv(url)
condicao = (banco['Customer_Age']) #Pode concatenar com outras colunas, atribuindo condicionais ou comparadores lógicos Ex: (banco['Customer_Age]) & ((banco['Gender']=="Male")) | ((banco['Gender']=="Female"))
maior_valor = banco.loc[condicao,"Customer_Age"].max() # Para trazer outras colunas, basta passar um array com os nomes delas, Ex: ["Customer_Age","Gender"]
print(maior_valor)
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Antes de mostrar como fazer isso, recomendo que repense no motivo de criar esse DataFrame. Vale dizer que está criando 1155625 linhas, o que pode ser custoso computacionalmente (se cada operação demorar 1 segundo, imagina o tempo que levará para completar o DataFrame).

Por sorte, pensando em problemas assim, o pandas tem algumas soluções. Usando `apply` e `where` do numpy e pandas conseguimos agilizar o processo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Abre o csv
df = pd.read_csv('df')
df.columns = ['id','name','total']

# Cria uma coluna para cada total existente
num_index = len(df.index)
for id1 in df.index:
    df[id1] = [df.loc[id1].total]*num_index
df.drop(columns=['name'], inplace=True)

# Compara cada coluna com o total
new_df = df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda x: np.where(x >= df.total, x.name, df.id), axis=0)

# Precisamos converter a matriz em #1,#2, Vencedor
new_df = new_df.stack().reset_index()
new_df.columns=['#1','#2','Vencedor']
display(new_df)
```

> Vale destacar que existem outras formas de fazer, e a que apresento aqui foi somente uma das possíveis.

**Resultado:**

[image: imagem do resultado]

Comment: Poxa ajudou demais, realmente fica enorme mas eu vou reduzir o dataset original para fazer essas operações já que é apenas para realizar alguns testes, muito obrigado!

Comment: Se possível, adicione como "resposta aceita" para que pessoas que tem problemas similares ao seu encontrem rapidamente a resposta. @DavysonRibeiro